# ARkit - Loading .scn file from Web-Server URL in SCNScene

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode, scnscene

I am using ARKit for my application and I try to dynamically load .scn files from my web-server(URL)

Here is a part of my code

```
 let urlString = "https://da5645f1.ngrok.io/mug.scn"
        let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: request,
                completionHandler: { (location:URL?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?)
                -> Void in
                print("location:\(String(describing: location))")
                let locationPath = location!.path
                let documents:String = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/mug.scn"
                ls = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents"
                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                if (fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documents)){
                     try! fileManager.removeItem(atPath: documents)
                }
                try! fileManager.moveItem(atPath: locationPath, toPath: documents)
                print("new location:\(documents)")
                let node = SCNNode()
                let scene =  SCNScene(named:"mug.scn", inDirectory: ls)
                let nodess = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Mug", recursively: true)
                node.addChildNode(nodess!)
                let nodeArray = scene!.rootNode.childNodes
                for childNode in nodeArray {
                    node.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
                }
                 self.addChildNode(node)
                 self.modelLoaded = true

        })
        downloadTask.resume()
```

Nslog:

```
location:Optional(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A1B996D7-ABE9-4000-91DB-2370076198D5/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_duDlwf.tmp)

new location:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A1B996D7-ABE9-4000-91DB-2370076198D5/Documents/mug.scn
```

.scn file downloading with the above mentioned(new location) file path.. but when i try to use this downloaded file in `SCNScene`

```
let scene =  SCNScene(named:"mug.scn", inDirectory: ls)
```

always scene value is `nil`. 
error

> Thread 4: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

how to resolve this issues. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About `init?(named: String)`, the documentation says:

> Loads a scene from a file with the specified name in the app’s main bundle

since you don't have such file inside the main bundle (is coming from a download), you may try with the following constructor:

```
init(url: URL, options: [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption : Any]? = nil)
```

so your code might be:

```
do {
   let documents = "yourValidPath"
   let scene = try SCNScene(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: documents), options: nil)
} catch {}
```

Comment: @ Andrea Mugnain. if i have .scn and  texture(3d model image) files in server side. how can i load. please help me. thanks

Comment: do you want to apply a previously downloaded texture to a `SCNMaterial`? or do you need to set `overrideAssetURLs` for your scene?

Comment: yes but i am not sure how to download and use models.scnassets.

Comment: here an explanation about programmatically setup a texture on a material: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34051972/2450755

Answer (score 0):

```
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let pathToObject = documentDirectory + "ship.scn"
    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToObject)

    guard let cshipScene = try? SCNScene(url: fileUrl, options: nil) else { return }
    let shipNode = SCNNode()
    let shipSceneChildNodes = shipScene.rootNode.childNodes
    for childNode in shipSceneChildNodes {
        shipNode.addChildNode(childNode)
    }

    node.addChildNode(shipNode)
```

Comment: this can't load a model from a remote url.